# MarkLogic ml-gradle configuration to set `assignment policy` for database?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

As in Marklogic version `10.0-2.1` the default `assignment policy` for a new database is `segment`.

I want to set it to `bucket`(same as used in old ML versions), so what is the ml-gradle configuration (`parameter` and `value`) for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Configuring-resources for guidance on how to configure something via the ML Admin GUI first, and then using the Manage API to determine what the JSON looks like.

You can also try configuring it directly via the Manage docs at http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/databases - look for assignment-policy on that page - but I usually find the Admin approach easier.